# select fields from table where id not in another table in mysql [not working]

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, dml

I'm trying to fetch data from a table and that id is not in another table. I referenced some code example to solve this but it didn't still work. I tried two style for this. My tried sql code is as below and please help me. Thank.

**Style 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM quotation q
WHERE q.quotationId NOT IN (SELECT ip.quotation_id FROM invest_project ip)
```

**Style 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM quotation q
LEFT JOIN invest_project ip
ON q.quotationId = ip.quotation_id
WHERE q.quotationId IS NULL
```

Comment: What error you are getting..

Comment: No record is found dude: SELECT *
FROM quotation q
LEFT JOIN invest_project ip
ON q.quotationId = ip.quotation_id
WHERE q.quotationId IS NULL;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.032 sec. */

Comment: does q.quotationId IS NULL in some records...??

Comment: Dude, I just want Left Excluding JOIN and so..... left table id should not be null but right table should be null. Yes, got it. Thank for your suggestion.

Comment: it works with this code : SELECT *
FROM quotation q
LEFT JOIN invest_project ip
ON q.quotationId = ip.quotation_id
WHERE ip.quotation_id IS NULL

Comment: its your Style2..there is no change in it...by the way first one fetched me the records where quotationId  is not null and not in second table...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc51fb/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select *  
from [Table1] AS T1  
where not exists( select * from [Table2] AS T2 where T1.ID = T2.ID)
```

This Work For Me

Comment: Works for me as well

Answer (score 2):

Try without alias...

```
SELECT * FROM quotation WHERE quotation.quotationId NOT IN (SELECT quotation_id FROM invest_project)
```

Comment: Actually I appreciate for your suggestion. with your suggestion I can solve it with another method. Your code is work at sql fiddle. here is I also create schema and dml similar my table. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cb99/1). But it doesn't work at my database. However, I really appreciate for your suggestions and answer dude.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify condition to not display null value data so 
try this

```
SELECT *
FROM quotation q
WHERE q.quotationId NOT IN (SELECT ip.quotation_id FROM invest_project ip) or q.quotationId is null
```